# Avoid hyperref warnings in moderncv

Tags: hyperref, warnings, moderncv

Whenever I compile a CV with `moderncv`, I get four warnings by `hyperref`. There don't seem to be any serious problems connected to them, yet they bug me. I like my documents to compile without warnings. **How can I avoid these warnings?** (Preferably without patching `moderncv.cls` itself, I'd rather add a few lines in each of my CVs.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\cvline{always}{King of the World}

\end{document}
```

The warnings:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' is turned off
(hyperref)                because \thepage is undefined.

Package hyperref Warning: Option `baseurl' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 6.

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagemode' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 6.

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfstartpage' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 6.
```

---

UPDATE:

Version 0.19 (2012/02/06) of `moderncv` only produces these warnings, the latter of which appears to be new:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' is turned off
(hyperref)                because \thepage is undefined.

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 6.
```

Comment: <rant>I find it easier to not to use `moderncv` than fix all its bugs.</rant>

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: Well, but not every LaTeX user has the level of expertise and the typesetting skills you have `;)`

Comment: I put together a smashing custom CV, and I'm hardly an expert. You should give it a go!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as _too localized_ because it doesn't apply to current systems anymore (cf. [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77819/4012)). It makes my heart bleed to have a question of mine closed for the first time on tex.sx, but alas ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the advent of `moderncv` version 1.1.3, **all of these warnings have disappeared**.
If you still get them, update your `moderncv`!

Changelog:

> version 1.1.3 (10 Aug 2012)
>    - corrected a longstanding issue causing hyperref to issue two warnings  regarding its "pdfpagelabels" option, as pointed out and
>   solved by P. Leifeld  ([launchpad bug #1035466](https://bugs.launchpad.net/moderncv/+bug/1035466)).

The minimal code requirements seem to have changed as well, you now need to declare a `\moderncvstyle`; `\maketitle` now is called `\makecvtitle`, which isn't necessary for an MWE however (I don't recall if it was earlier or if I had put it there for looks).

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document} 

%\makecvtitle

\cvline{always}{King of the World}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can avoid the first warning by setting the option before `\documentclass`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels=false}{hyperref}
```

You can't avoid the other three without patching moderncv. moderncv sets some hyperref options incorrectly in a `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why these incorrect options aren't patched? The latest version of `moderncv` was deployed not even a week ago.

Comment: Probably nobody told the author about the problem. Did you write him?

Comment: I just e-mailed him. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you please enumerate the incorrect `hyperref` options set by `moderncv`.  This will be helpful to fix them by passing the correct arguments using the `PassOptionsToPackage` trick that you propose here.

Answer (score 5):

You may deactivate all warnings of package hyperref before loading the class:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\PackageWarning{%
  \edef\pkgname{#1}\edef\hyperrefname{hyperref}%
  \ifx\pkgname\hyperrefname
    \expandafter\gobblethree
  \fi
}{}{\undefined}
\newcommand*{\gobblethree}[3]{}

\documentclass{moderncv}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\cvline{always}{King of the World}

\end{document}
```

Nevertheless `moderncv` does some strange things (e.g. forcing option `pdftex`).

Comment: While this works, I'd still like to get actual warnings by `hyperref`, I guess I should've specified that; i.e. I'm looking for a way to rule out the reasons for the warnings.

Comment: In this case best would be to fix the buggy class, e.g., write a bug report to the author.

Answer (score 3):

*(A bit late, but it might still be helpful for someone...)*

Using the latest version (1.0, released in March 2012) of [`moderncv` from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) removed all but the first warning.

For some reason, setting the `pdfpagelabels` option with `\PassOptionsToPackage` did not work for me. I finally decided to use the [`silence` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence) to silence all warnings from the `hyperref` package, by placing the following code before `\documentclass`:

```
\RequirePackage[]{silence}

\WarningsOff[hyperref]
```

It is not perfect, but I consider it acceptable until `moderncv` gets better at playing nice with others...