# bigfoot.sty:61: Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used

Tags: errors, hyperref, warnings, bigfoot

As simple as it can be:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}

    Bit cut\footnote{bigfoot}.

\end{document}
```

Creates this warning `` bigfoot.sty:61: Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used ``.

These are the code lines (61) on the `bigfoot`:

```
File: D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/bigfoot/bigfoot.sty
58: \ifx\hypersetup\@undefined
59:   \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
60: \else
61:   \hypersetup{hyperfootnotes=false}
62: \fi
```

Can the `bigfoot` package do something like:

```
\ifx\hypersetup\@undefined
  \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\else
  \ifx hyperfootnotes_enabled
    \hypersetup{hyperfootnotes=false}
  \if
\fi
```

So I can get rid of this warning?

I cannot just load `bigfoot` before `hyperref` because I need to load `bigfoot` by last due errors as [Animate gives errors when I also use bigfoot or cprotect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299348/animate-gives-errors-when-i-also-use-bigfoot-or-cprotect) I getting on my main document class.

---

Related questions:

1. [Avoid hyperref warnings in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34910/avoid-hyperref-warnings-in-moderncv)
2. [Hyperref, Natbib: Curious backref behaviour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88494/hyperref-natbib-curious-backref-behaviour)

---

Compilation log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.8.23)  22 NOV 2017 20:45
entering extended mode
**./test2.tex
(test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
\onelineskip=\skip41
\lxvchars=\skip42
\xlvchars=\skip43
\@memcnta=\count79
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count80
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
Package: ifetex 2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
\stockheight=\skip44
\stockwidth=\skip45
\trimtop=\skip46
\trimedge=\skip47

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo
File: mem10.clo 2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
)
...
    defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.st
y
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks24
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen147
\Hy@linkcounter=\count137
\Hy@pagecounter=\count138

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count139

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4498.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4503.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4506.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4513.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4518.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4751.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count140

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5104.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen148
\Fld@menulength=\count141
\Field@Width=\dimen149
\Fld@charsize=\dimen150
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6358.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6363.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6366.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6373.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6378.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6383.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6388.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6428.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6432.
\Hy@abspage=\count142
\c@Item=\count143
\c@Hfootnote=\count144
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memhfixc.sty
Package: memhfixc 2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir cl
ass
\c@memhycontfloat=\count145
\c@Hpagenote=\count146
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count147
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count148

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip185
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\bigfoot\bigfoot.sty
Package: bigfoot 2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work


Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 61.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ncctools\manyfoot.sty
Package: manyfoot 2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ncctools\nccfoots.sty
Package: nccfoots 2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
)
\MFL@columnwidth=\dimen151
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\bigfoot\suffix.sty
Package: suffix 2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\bigfoot\perpage.sty
Package: perpage 2014/10/25 2.0 Reset/sort counters per page
\c@abspage=\count149
)
\footnotewidowpenalty=\count150
\footnoteclubpenalty=\count151
\finalfootnotewidowpenalty=\count152
\c@FN@totalid=\count153
\c@pp@a@FN@totalid=\count154
\FN@id=\count155
\FN@master=\marks1
\FN@slave=\marks2
\FN@color=\marks3
\FN@outervsize=\dimen152
\FN@vsize=\skip186
\FN@insertions=\box29
\FN@output=\toks25
\FN@tempbox=\box30
\FN@savebox=\insert194
\FN@topmarkbox=\box31
\FN@outputflag=\count156
\FN@myvsize=\dimen153
\bigfoottolerance=\count157
)
(D:\User\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTo
ols\b98d701d6340232fe19ea13f16f5a620\test2.aux)
\openout1 = `test2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box32
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 9.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count158
)
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 9.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 9.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 9.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 9.

(D:\User\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTo
ols\b98d701d6340232fe19ea13f16f5a620\test2.out)
(D:\User\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTo
ols\b98d701d6340232fe19ea13f16f5a620\test2.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `test2.out'.

\footinsdefault=\insert193
\FN@cache193=\box33
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 11.
 [1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 13.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 13.

(D:\User\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTo
ols\b98d701d6340232fe19ea13f16f5a620\test2.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 13.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 13.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `test2.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 13.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8434 strings out of 493314
 120353 string characters out of 3134142
 230679 words of memory out of 3000000
 11941 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 9642 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 33i,10n,23p,183b,340s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exi
st, replaced by a fixed one

{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.en
c}<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0600.
pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm070
0.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0
800.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfr
m1000.pfb>
Output written on D:\User\SublimeText\D
ata\Cache\LaTeXTools\b98d701d6340232fe19ea13f16f5a620\test2.pdf (1 page, 49044 
bytes).
PDF statistics:
 30 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 3 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: have you tried loading bigfoot before hyperref?

Comment: I cannot do that because `hyperref` is loaded by my main class `abntex2`, and I need to load `bigfoot` after some other package, which I do not know exactly, otherwise I got a lot of errors. (This is why I load it by last)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load `bigfoot` this way

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\truehypersetup\hypersetup
\renewcommand\hypersetup[1]{}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\let\hypersetup\truehypersetup

\begin{document}

    Bit cut\footnote{bigfoot}.

\end{document}
```

PLUS you need to pass option `hyperfootnotes=false` to hyperref, as it seems to be required for compatibility with `bigfoot`. So for example

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\let\truehypersetup\hypersetup
\renewcommand\hypersetup[1]{}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\let\hypersetup\truehypersetup

\begin{document}

    Bit cut\footnote{bigfoot}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clever, as long as `bigfoot` does not do other calls to `hyperrefsetup`, however on this case, we just need do these calls for him.

Comment: yes you are right I did check that `\hypersetup` was used only once in bigfoot.sty but it may possibly be used by other packages it requires such as manyfoot.sty. For the latter it doesn't seem to be the case but it has dependencies. By using `\renewcommand\hypersetup[1]{\renewcommand\hypersetup[1]{\ERROR}}` I convinced myself it was all ok.