# How to comment a package line before loading the package?

Tags: etoolbox, comments, patching, bigfoot, xpatch

I can solve the issue [bigfoot.sty:61: Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402652/bigfoot-sty61-package-hyperref-warning-option-hyperfootnotes-has-already-be) by commenting out the line 61:

```
File: D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/bigfoot/bigfoot.sty
57: \ProcessOptions*
58: \ifx\hypersetup\@undefined
59:   \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
60: \else
61:   % \hypersetup{hyperfootnotes=false}
62: \fi
```

Directly on the package `bigfoot.sty`, however I would not like to have to comment this line everywhere I go, or for all the other documents which do not required this fix.

How could I just be able to patch the `bigfoot` package like I patch a LaTeX command with `xpatch` or `etoolbox`?

Comment: You can patch macros, but not code lines, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **workaround** for your problem can be the following:

1. Copy `bigfoot.sty` to `mybigfoot.sty`. Save it in the same directory you have your TeX code.
2. Comment line 61 and save `mybigfoot.sty`
3. If you need the new version `mybigfoot.sty` instead `bigfoot.sty` in your TeX code simple change the loading of the package from `\usepackage{bigfoot}` to `\usepackage{mybigfoot}`.