# How to silence a multi line warning?

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, warnings, bigfoot, silence

I am trying to silence the warning from the question [bigfoot.sty:61: Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402652/bigfoot-sty61-package-hyperref-warning-option-hyperfootnotes-has-already-be)

I tried:

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*{hyperref}{Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
```

And it works, however I want to only silence that warning which specifically points to the line 61, not all the other warning which just starts with:

```
Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used
```

Then I tried writing:

```
\WarningFilter*{hyperref}{Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used,.*setting the option has no effect on input line 61.}
```

And:

```
\WarningFilter*{hyperref}{Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used,%
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 61.}
```

But none of them worked. How can I silence a multi line warning?

```
...(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip185
) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\bigfoot\bigfoot.sty
Package: bigfoot 2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work


Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 61.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ncctools\manyfoot.sty
Package: manyfoot 2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ncctools\nccfoots.sty
Package: nccfoots 2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
)
...
```

---

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*{hyperref}{Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 61.}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}

    Bit cut\footnote{bigfoot}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To silence a multi-line warning, you need to include the appropriate code associated with the warning. Let's see what the actual message is from [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) via the macro `\Hy@WarnOptionDisabled`:

```
\def\Hy@WarnOptionDisabled#1{%
  \Hy@Warning{%
    Option `#1' has already been used,\MessageBreak
    setting the option has no effect%
  }%
}
```

The warning includes a `\MessageBreak`, so one can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*
  {hyperref}
  {Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used, \MessageBreak
    setting the option has no effect}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}

Text.

\end{document}
```

Note though that  `on line 61.` does not form part of the warning message. Instead,  `on line < lineno >.` forms part of the kernel macro that is with any warning that results in a (subsequent) call to `\GenericWarning`:

```
\def\on@line{ on input line \the\inputlineno}
%...
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericWarning}[2]{%
   \begingroup
      \def\MessageBreak{^^J#1}%
      \set@display@protect
      \immediate\write\@unused{^^J#2\on@line.^^J}%
   \endgroup
}
```