# Can I silence a warning which is coming from a file like `bigfoot.sty`?

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, warnings, bigfoot, silence

I am trying to specifically silence a warning which happens a a specific file called `bigfoot.sty` [bigfoot.sty:61: Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402652/bigfoot-sty61-package-hyperref-warning-option-hyperfootnotes-has-already-be)

Looking over the `silence` package documentation http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/silence/silence-doc.pdf it seems impossible to silence a warning for a specific line as `on input line 61`.

However, can I silence a warning which is coming from a file like `bigfoot.sty`?

This is the code I tried to so far:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*{hyperref}{Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used,\MessageBreak setting the option has no effect on input line 61.}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}

    Bit cut\footnote{bigfoot}.

\end{document}
```

But due the `on input line 61.` at the end of the warning, it is not being silenced.

This is the warning:

```
D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\bigfoot\bigfoot.sty:61: Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 61.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific message, you can silence it using

```
\makeatletter
\let\tempHOD\Hy@WarnOptionDisabled
\renewcommand{\Hy@WarnOptionDisabled}[1]{}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\let\Hy@WarnOptionDisabled\tempHOD
\makeatother
```

If you want to ignore this warning *specifically* for a call that uses `hyperfootnotes`, you can check whether that option is passed using

```
\renewcommand{\Hy@WarnOptionDisabled}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{hyperfootnotes}=0\else
    \tempHOD{#1}%
  \fi}
```

Fundamentally though, the problem arises from an inappropriate loading order. Loading in the order

```
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

runs without warning.